# How to access a on change event of an input tag in a datatable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, datatables

I can't access on change event of an input box in a datatable.
I used datatable as a separate partial view.
The on change event is not working

This is the input field of the datatable.

```
<td> <input class="form-control rateInput" type="text" value=@item.Rate /> </td>
```

I have tried to change and both didn't work

```
$('#clientData tbody').on('change', '.rateInput', function ()
 {
   alert('Hello');
 });
```

**AND**

```
$("#clientData").on("change", ".rateInput", function()
{ 
 alert("hi"); 
});
```

datatable id is clientData